# International political parties

Tags: parties, international

Sinn Féin won the popular vote in the recent Irish general elections. As a British person, I'm also aware that Sinn Féin have MPs in Northern Ireland, which is part of the United Kingdom; a separate state to the Republic of Ireland.

How common is it to have political parties operate internationally (where nation is defined, say, per UN membership)? I'm aware of ideological parties -- e.g., The Communist Party -- that span borders, but was under the impression that the various national versions thereof were administratively separate from one another.

Comment: Note that Sinn Féin would quite vehemently insist that they are **not** an international political party at all. This is something of a special case.